# WPF Webcam Integration

Tags: wpf, silverlight, activex, webcam, wpf-mediakit

I am trying to get webcam integration working with a WPF application. There have been a few questions here about getting a webcam functioning in WPF, in this case for image capture. Many people recommend the VideoCaptureElement from the [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/). We are currently using this, however it doesn't appear to be particularly performant, there is high CPU usage, and the application experiences slow down after regular use of the camera.

We are looking into either integrating a Silverlight hosted solution, or an ActiveX webcam control hosted using a WindowsFormsHost. Has anyone successfully used either approach in a WPF application?

Comment: Looks like this Codeplex project http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/ provides a Webcam control for WPF that cares for CPU usage.

Comment: There is also another WPF Webcam project on CodePlex called Easy Web Cam. http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/ Have you tried any of these other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided to drop WPF MediaKit because it proved not to work on certain cameras (to do with pixel formats), and the project wasn't actively being developed.

Instead, we are now using the `Capture` class in the [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) project, which works very well. There are lots of articles online about using Emgu CV to perform webcam integration.

Comment: What about to use MS Expression Encoder 4? It is free 100% and we can sure it will support ANY WebCam...

Comment: You can see an example using Emgu CV here - http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/level-1---lets-make-a-camera-application

Comment: Thanks for answer... I have downloaded source code http://www.box.com/s/s3o8unva0sdlma9zl5p5 and it has some errors... I am guessing to use MS Expression Encoder SDK solution... It is stable 100%